# J4 REST API Get users how to filter?

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-api

The J4 REST API allows me to GET a full list of users, but I have not found any example of how to filter such a request, for example by searching by userID or email.

When I look at the code for the users API controller (/api/components/com_users/src/Controller/UsersController.php), I see a bunch of code for filtering.

I have experimented with parameters and body JSON to try to trigger filtering, but nothing seems to work--it always returns the full list.  For example, I tried adding

```
{"filter":["search":"montgomery-scott"]}
```

to the body.

Can anyone provide a sample GET request that shows filtering syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include filter parameter in the endpoint URL:

```
/api/index.php/v1/users?filter[search]=montgomery-scott&filter[active]=1
```

Strangely, this is not documented in Joomla Core APIs [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Joomla_Core_APIs).

Comment: That works!  Thanks.

Comment: And a documentation bug report here: https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/41696